# "Cannot redeclare class" Error in a Interface [PHP]

Tags: php, interface

I am getting this error: "Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class iterator in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Projeto_Novo\php\Iterator.php on line 3"

The thing is, I only import this Interface one time, not even in this file. As shown by Sublime Text 2, the only times the word "iterator" (not case sensitive) appears in my project are:

```
Searching 47 files for "Iterator"

C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Projeto_Novo\php\Iterator.php:
    1  <?php
    2  
    3: interface iterator{
    4   public function next();
    5   public function hasNext();
    6  }

C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Projeto_Novo\php\ListMine.php:
    1  <?php
    2: include_once "Iterator.php";
    3  include_once "\VO\Mine.php";
    4  
    5: class ListMine implements iterator{
    6  
    7   private static $MAXMINES = 3;
3 matches across 2 files
```

I have no idea what can be causing this.

Comment: The Iteraror Interface is already part of the SPL http://php.net/manual/de/class.iterator.php - If you want to keep using your own Iterator class you have to namespace it

Comment: I did not know this. Thank you.
Well, that was quick.

Comment: And my "reflex advice" in such case is to use whatever the language(/bundled standard library/framework) provides. Even when the interface is (slightly) different from one's own idea. Those (now common and basic) interfaces thrive on their broad usage and support. So, first evaluate if you can live with the existing defintion before considering to deviate from the "mainstream".

Comment: @VolkerK Yeah, I would usually do the same, but in this case I cannot. It is for a college work and it was specified that we must create our Iterator. But thanks for the advice. :)